# When I boot Ubuntu 16.04, I'm getting a blank purple screen. How do I fix it?

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, intel-graphics, hda-intel

It was working perfectly and suddenly this is happening. All of my work is in that and I don't have a backup.
I can access the GRUB. So in recovery mode
I am not able to enable networking.
This is the error I'm getting.
[image: This]

Dpkg is also not working. I think it needs networking to be enabled.

When I choose failsafex, I'm getting this error:

[image: Fatal Server Error [EE] No Screens found]

I think this is the main problem.
I'm using Dell Inspiron 7000 with Intel HD graphic card. I have dual-booted with Windows 10.
And while using Windows 10, I got that blue screen error message saying: WHEA_Uncorrectable_Error. I think it might be related.